# Split videofile during recording an video iphone 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i have coded a videocamera app for the iphone 4 with functions like lock focus..
i have one big problem. when i record 720p videos with it and make longer movies than about 1 hour the file is getting over 4gg. when i now stop the recording there a problems with saving. i almost got every time a broken mov file after it. tried it with some other ways but than the recording stopps at 4gb or begin to overwrite it.

is there a possibilty to record to multiple files that when 2048 mb are reached he writes the video to a second mov called part2 or something like that without stop and start recording again? (so after i record 2 hours i got 3 parts containing the complete movie i shot)

kind regards

Comment: quick unrelated question..why is 1 hour a feasible length for a movie for you? I'm not sure users expect that at all.

Comment: i want that the users can use all the space they have. so if they want to record a 3 hour movie it should be possible

Comment: umm, ok. Well breaking it up is definitely the (only) way to do it, but I don't know of a way to do it without stopping/starting a new video. good luck.

Comment: ok thx i hope its anybody here who can help me with it